# How to insert a multiple else in a case statement in sql server with different conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case

I'm really struggling with how to insert an else in my case statement with different conditions...I'm not sure if it's the syntax that is wrong or what?it's not working, I don't have any error messages, the problem is I still have a Null in my alias for some cases...

```
    UPDATE Table
    SET Alias = SUBSTRING(Names, 10, 40);

    UPDATE Table
            SET Alias = CASE WHEN  Alias LIKE 'core.user%'  OR Alias LIKE  'core.idea%' OR Alias LIKE'core.form%' 
                             THEN STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 5, 0, '-') 
                             WHEN  Alias LIKE 'core.badge%'  OR Alias LIKE  'core.award%' OR Alias LIKE 'core.field%' OR Alias LIKE 'core.audit%' OR Alias LIKE 'core.event%'
                             THEN STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 6, 0, '-')
                             ELSE CASE len(Alias) when charindex('.',Alias) +4 then Alias
                                  ELSE CASE len(Alias)when charindex('.',Alias)+ 5 then Alias
                                        END
                                   END
                         END;

     /*the result for this part is:*/
     Names                                 Alias
     idealink.core.userbadge               core.user-badge
     idealink.core.ideacategories          core.idea-categories
     idealink.core.awardtype               core.award-type        /*till here it's working,but when*/
     idealink.core.user                    NULL        ---I'd like to have (core.user)----
     idealink.core.idea                    NULL        ---I'd like to have (core.idea)----
     idealink.core.award                   NULL        ---I'd like to have (core.award)---- 

     /*I think the problem is here, I'm having Null*/
```

The purpose of all this is get rid of the idealink, and put a dash between the words when the string is too long after the core. ;but in some cases the string is not so long, so I don't need the dash like (core.user,core.idea,core.award) and so on, just get rid of the idealink.

I really appreciate any help of you guys.
Thanks

Comment: A `CASE` can't have multiple `ELSE` clauses. `ELSE` is for when no `WHEN` resolves to true.

Comment: Humpf, Do you have any idea how i can solve this?(I'm newbie).. :(

Comment: Those aren't multiple `ELSE` clauses, @Larnu. They're nested. The `ELSE` for the primary `CASE` is an embedded `CASE`. The (arguably poor) formatting in the question just makes it appear to be syntactically invalid.

Comment: Yes, it was more that the OP appeared to suggest that they wanted multiple else's for a single `CASE` , @EricBrandt .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because core.user and core.userbridge would both fall under the criteria you defined for Alias like 'core.user%'

To explicitly set values for core.user,core.idea,core.award, you would do as follows.

Check the portion between the /****************/

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Alias = SUBSTRING(Names, 10, 40);

UPDATE Table
   SET Alias = CASE /*****************************************************************************************/
                    WHEN Alias in('core.user','core.idea','core.award')
                    THEN Alias                  
                    /*****************************************************************************************/
                    WHEN Alias LIKE 'core.user%'  OR Alias LIKE  'core.idea%' OR Alias LIKE'core.form%' 
                    THEN STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 5, 0, '-') 
                    WHEN  Alias LIKE 'core.badge%'  OR Alias LIKE  'core.award%' OR Alias LIKE 'core.field%' OR Alias LIKE 'core.audit%' OR Alias LIKE 'core.event%'
                    THEN STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 6, 0, '-')
                    ELSE CASE len(Alias) when charindex('.',Alias) +4 then Alias
                         ELSE CASE len(Alias) when charindex('.',Alias)+ 5 then Alias
                               END
                         END
                END;
```

Comment: OMG, you are totally right @George Joseph, I got it! Thank you so much!!  :)